# IE upload same file with angular file uploader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I am using angular and have a simple file upload input on the page. In IE, I cannot upload the same file twice in a row because onchange is not triggered since the file name is the same. I have tried several different ways to set the value to null or blank but it does not seem to help.

html:

```
<input id="frontFileSelect" type="file" class="ng-hide" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getFrontImage(files); this.value = null; return false;" ng-accept="'*.pdf,*.jpg,*.png,*.tif,*.tiff'" ng-multiple="false" />
```

I have tried adding:

```
onclick="this.value = null;" and onclick="this.value = '';"
```

Like:

```
<input id="frontFileSelect" type="file" class="ng-hide" onclick="this.value = null;" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getFrontImage(files); this.value = null; return false;" ng-accept="'*.pdf,*.jpg,*.png,*.tif,*.tiff'" ng-multiple="false" />
```

I have also tried adding code in my controller to reset value:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#frontFileSelect')).val('');
```

Nothing seems to work.. IE always has the same value for file name. This seems to be a common problem but I have tried all of the proposed solutions I could find and nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you list the proposed solutions that haven't worked? Also can you show the larger context for onclick? Are you sure this refers to what you think it does?

Comment: Please see above for the onclick context.

Comment: @sunny - the solutions are to manually reset the value to blank or null, so that IE recognizes the change event when you select the same file. But, when I change the value, it is never actually changed. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. That makes sense now.